# Solr sort after boost?

Tags: sorting, solr, solr-boost

Is it possible to put boosted fields in front of other **if its already sorted**?

I have products that are sorted by **popular ASC** (its integer), but there are some specific products that I want to boost in front of other products, no matter what value is popular.

I am new with Solr, and I have got so far that I need to use **edismax**, right?
But I dont exactly understand how it works, I always get popular products sorted first.

I have following query params:

```
"sort": "popular ASC",
"bq": "(product_id: 123)^100",
```

Answer (score 4):

This is called `elevation` in search.
In solr, `QueryElevationComponent` might be what you need,

**Brief usage step:**

- Config the component in `solrconfig.xml`.
- Add a `elevate.xml`, and define the top rows, usually by specify the doc ids.
- When query, use param `enableElevation` / `forceElevation` / .. to specify whether enable elevation. And yes, it works well with parser `DisMax` or `eDisMax`.

**Refer:**

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

---

### @Update

I updated the above refer link with a better one, check that.

The doc id is the `id` field of the doc.

**What's more important are:**

- The `queryFieldType` attribute of `<searchComponent>`, it specify the field type, thus decide the analyzer used, for English text, you might need `text_en`, don't use the default `string`, which won't analyze the query input.
- Use request-handler `/elevate` instead of `/select`, when query.
- Add the param `enableElevation=true&forceElevation=true`, so that to enable elevate sorts.
- the additional field "[elevated]" indicate whether a record is elevated, it has boolean value,
  could add the field in 'fl' param,
  e.g `fl=*,[elevated]`

**About params:**

- `enableElevation`, whether enable elevation, it don't override sort, means when `sort` param is specified, whether elevated docs are still on top depends on `forceElevation` param.
- `forceElevation`, whether force elevation, it will override sort, means when `sort` param is specified, will still put elevated docs at top, then sort other docs.

---

### Here is my example:

**solrconfig.xml**: (add before `</config>`)

```
  <!-- elevation -->
  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <str name="queryFieldType">text_en</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

**elevate.xml**: (e.g put it in `solr-5.4.1/server/solr/dummy/conf/`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<elevate>

 <query text="Eric">
  <doc id="1" />
  <doc id="2" />
  <doc id="3" />
 </query>

</elevate>
```

This file is load once on startup, after change, need reload the core, e.g via solr admin.

**query example:**

- http://localhost:8983/solr/dummy/elevate?q=eric&fl=*%2C%5Belevated%5D&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=name&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&enableElevation=true&forceElevation=true

Comment: I don't really understand how this work. I am stuck in doc id part, where can I see doc id? <doc id="???" />. It's unique every time when I execute query?

Comment: Ok. Now it returns only elevated docs I specified, not sure how to mix with other docs. But actually now I am not sure if this is what I am looking for, because these specific docs must be dynamical - in my system they can be added, removed and their order can be changed. Plus after these docs must follow remaining docs based on **popular ASC**. I could make script that generate elevate.xml docs inside, but still then I need to reload core every time I change these docs..

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks 
 
1) They do include the match docs for sure, don't know why you didn't see that. 2) To make the ids dynamic, you can edit the elevate.xml file by program, automatically, then call a reload by program automatically, this need some utility class. 3) Another solution is to add a priority field to your data, and boost the field greatly, so that they always appear in front when match they query, in this case only matched rows will show, but with elevate non-mache rows could also be configured to show.

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks  If u have read the doc carefully, put elevate.xml in <dataDir>/ then the file will be load for each request, not just on startup, thus reload by hand is not necessary. There is a trade off, depends on the traffic of your sites.

Comment: @EricWang We are able to get this done with your help. Thanks. However, we are unable to get elevated results on top when we apply sort by popularity field. We need to put elevated results on top of sorted by that field. Kindly advise how we can do that?

Comment: @Krunal Not sure what you mean by `apply sort by popularity field`.

Comment: @EricWang Sorry. I should be more clear. I mean to apply elevation along with sorting. Pls check , I posted a separate question as well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156686/getting-solr-elevated-results-on-top-of-sorted-by-field-results

Comment: @Krunal Don't forget the `enableElevation=true&forceElevation=true` parameters, try add that when query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **edismax** the right way you need to consider sorting by relevance score. The `bf` (boost function) just apply an addictive factor to the score but it doesn't make any change to the order because you are not sorting by the score. If you want the `popular` factor increase the document score you can use for example the `boost` parameter to do this. Follow an example you can use to get good results:

```
"sort": "score DESC",
"bq": "(product_id: 123)^100",
"boost": "popular"
```

Comment: This almost works for me. BUT **"boost": "popular"** goes DESC (from higher to lower) - how to boost ASC?

Answer (score 2):

```
"sort": "popular ASC",
"bq": "(product_id: 123)^100",
```

Convert this to this:

```
"sort": "score desc, popular ASC",
"bq": "(product_id: 123)^100",
```

Comment: this is what i needed but the other way around, popular then score, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, this component respects the requested sort parameter: if the request asks to sort by date, it will order the results by date. If forceElevation=true (the default), results will first return the boosted docs, then order by date.